# change specific columns of data frame using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame 3 columns: ["`date`", "`volume`", "`ID`"]. ID=0,1,2...15.
I would like to create new data frame: keep all rows with `ID=5`.

Other rows: still keep them all, but set the `row["volume"] = 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First copy your dataframe:

```
df_new = df.copy()
```

Then, using [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), set volume to 0 for your criteria:

```
df_new.loc[df_new['ID'] != 5, 'volume'] = 0
```